# Prove that T is transitive if and only if the score of the $k^{th}$ vertex ($s_k$) = '$k-1$' for $k =1,2,\ldots. n $

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

There is a transitive tournament (T) with $n > 1$  vertices and the  score sequence is defined as $s_1, s_2, \ldots,s_n$

Prove that T is transitive if and only if the score of the $k^{th}$ vertex ($s_k$) = '$k-1$' for $k =1,2,\ldots. n $

i.e $s_k = k-1$ for all $k= 1,2,3,\ldots, n$

I have been researching and noticed that this is similar to the Landau's Theorem (1953), however i am completely lost with the proof. I know that the score is the out degree, and i know that the out degree is the total number of edges going out of the vertex which is of course also (0,1,2,3...n-1).

I know that a tournament must have a unique ranking, and i also know that at transitive tournament must have at least one in degree on 0 .

I also know that a transitive tournament must have a score sequence of $(0,1,2,3,...n-1)$, and obviously the in degree is the number of edges minus that.

I have tried going along the lines of proof by contradiction, but i am completely stuck

I would really like to find a proof for this, please help!

Comment: What are the conditions on the scores ?  How exactly are they defined ?

Comment: The score is the out degree for that specific vertex. So a tournament is a directed complete graph, for each edge in the graph one end adds one to the in-degree of one vertex, and one edge adds one to the out degree of another vertex. The score sequence is the score of each vertex in order of size. e.g the score of vertex k is the number of edges with an arrow pointing out of vertex k

Comment: Okay.  Now there are 2 directions to prove (the if, and the only  if).  Which direction are you having problems with ?  It seems you know that a transitive tournament has out-degree sequence $(0,1, \ldots, n - 1)$, which proves the 'only if' part.  Now if you have this out-degree sequence, you need to show you have transitivity.  Is that the troubling part ?

Comment: Yes, I've proved that $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ can be a score sequence of the vertex n by showing an example, but I'm stuck on proving the 'only if' part, where if T is transitive then the score sequence must be $0,1,\ldots, n-1$

Comment: Well an example is not enough.  What needs to be shown exactly for the 'if' part : if you get the outdegree sequence $(0, 1, \ldots, n - 1)$, then $T$ is always transitive.  Unless your example is perfectly general, you need something more (this direction can be proved by induction rather easily).  Actually, the 'only if' direction should be provable by induction as well.  Take your tournament with the described degree sequence.  Remove the vertex with outdegree $n - 1$.  You get a tournament with sequence $(0, 1, \ldots, n - 2)$, which should be transitive by induction.  Now add $n - 1$...

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that a transitive tournament with $n$ vertices has the score sequence of $(0,1,2,…,n−1)$. Now suppose that it holds for all the transitive tournaments.

The proof is by induction on the number of vertices of $T$, the result being trivial for transitive tournaments with at most two vertices.

Let T be a transitive tournament with $n+1$ vertices. We know that a tournament is an orientation of a complete graph. In addition, transitivity implies that $T$ is acyclic. So $T$ has a vertex $V$ with out-degree of $n$. If we delete $V$ and it's incident edges, then the graph that remains is a transitive tournament with $n$ vertices and it has a vertex with out-degree of $n-1$. By our induction hypothesis, this graph has the score sequence of $(0,1,2,…,n−1)$. Appending the score of V to it gives the score sequence of $T$ which is $(0,1,2,...,n)$.

---

Now we want to show that if score sequence $(S_1,S_2,S_3,...,S_n)$ where $S_k=k-1$ for all $k=1,2,3,…,n$ then $T$ is transitive.

Remove leaf vertex $V$ and it's incident edges. Removing $V$ will decrease all of the remaining vertices in-degrees by one so there will be another leaf vertex. Keep removing leaf vertices, we will eventually remove all vertices: The tournament is acyclic therefore transitive.